# Why are some SMS not showing up?

Tags: messages

Since yesterday text messages from one number are not showing up in messages on my Mac.

They show up ok on the phone though, and messages from other senders (myself, friends) show up on both phone and laptop.

I checked accounts and they are in sync, and the number is not blacklisted.

I have closed and restarted messages - no difference.

Any suggestions as to how to figure this out?

Comment: Text messages from other senders using SMS (and not iMessage) sent to your email address are still showing up on your Mac?

Comment: @fsb I think they do not. For sure an SMS I sent does not.